# RViz2 Show Trail not working

Tags: ros, rviz, path-planning

I'm going through the [MoveIt Quickstart in RViz](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html) guide and am trying to replicate Step 4: Use Motion Planning with the Kinova Gen 3. When following the instructions of un-checking the Show Trail box, planning some path from Start State to Goal State, and then checking Show Trail I do not see the arm's path as the documentation shows.

This is the expected display in RViz after following these instructions:
[image]

This is what my display is after following the exact instructions:
[image]

In the off chance that it is because my Start State is not at the same position of the arm itself I also will show it when they are coincident, there is still no Trail shown:
[image]